# android XPath, copy nodes from one document to another

Tags: android, xpath, appendchild, domexception

Hi I need to copy nodes from one XML into another one:

```
String _sPathOfrObj = "/response/grp/ofr/obj";
String _sPathHotelData = "/main/hotelData";
String _sPathStatus = "/main/status";
xpath.reset();
NodeList status = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate( _sPathStatus, details, XPathConstants.NODESET );
if(status.item( 0 ).getTextContent().equalsIgnoreCase( "ok" ))
{
    NodeList nodes3 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate( _sPathOfrObj, result, XPathConstants.NODESET );
    NodeList nodes4 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate( _sPathHotelData, details, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    minimum = Math.min( nodes3.getLength(), nodes4.getLength() );

    Log.i(CLASS_NAME, "obj="+nodes3.getLength());
    Log.i(CLASS_NAME, "hdat="+nodes4.getLength());

    for (i = 0; i < minimum; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            nodes3.item( i ).appendChild( nodes4.item( i ) );
        }
        catch(DOMException dome)
        {
            dome.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(CLASS_NAME, dome.code+"" );
        }
    }
}
```

but it generates an error, DOMException WRONG_DOCUMENT_ERR or when I will do `nodes4.item( i ).deepClone(true or false)` it will throw DOMException NAMESPACE_ERR

Is there a way to do it?

Many thanks

Comment: Hi, the following link is promissing [link](http://sevalapsha.wordpress.com/2008/06/26/copy-nodes-xml-documents-java-dom/#comment-249) but the sample code is somewhat incomplete and as I am new to Java programming it just confuses me more, it would be also good for me if someone would create working full example upon this link, ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to have it working, it is a mixture of my solution to overcome deepClone throwing NAMESPACE_ERR and the solution presented in the [**link**](http://sevalapsha.wordpress.com/2008/06/26/copy-nodes-xml-documents-java-dom/#comment-249).

Basically I wasn't able to make a copy of the given node without an error so I am flattening the XML to string and converting the string to new Node and by using the adoptNode I have my solution:)

I do realise that it is hell of a hack but it works for my tight deadline:)

The converting to string is done by using Transformer class as follows:

```
private static final String CLASS_NAME = "SendQueryTask";
//...
import java.io.StringWriter;

import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactoryConfigurationError;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
//...
private String transformXmlToString(Node node)
{
    Transformer transformer = null;
    try
    {
        transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
    }
    catch (TransformerConfigurationException e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (TransformerFactoryConfigurationError e)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if ( transformer != null )
    {
        transformer.setOutputProperty( OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes" );

        // initialize StreamResult with File object to save to file
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult( new StringWriter() );
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource( node );

        try
        {
            transformer.transform( source, result );
        }
        catch (TransformerException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String xmlString = result.getWriter().toString();
        Log.i( CLASS_NAME, "flattened=" + (xmlString) );

        return xmlString;
    }       
    return null;
}
```

and to convert it back to Node

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HTTP;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;

private Node dumbNodeCopy(Node item)
{
    String xmlString = transformXmlToString( item );

    if ( xmlString != null )
    {
        InputStream is = null;
        try
        {
            is = new ByteArrayInputStream( xmlString.getBytes( HTTP.UTF_8 ) );
        }
        catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if ( is != null )
        {
            Document doc = null;
            dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            try
            {
                db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                doc = db.parse( is );
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

            }
            catch (ParserConfigurationException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (SAXException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if ( doc != null ) return doc.getFirstChild();
        }
        return null;
    }
    return null;
```

and finally the copying

```
NodeList nodes3 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate( _sPathOfrObj, result,
        XPathConstants.NODESET );
NodeList nodes4 = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate( _sPathHotelData, details,
        XPathConstants.NODESET );
minimum = Math.min( nodes3.getLength(), nodes4.getLength() );

Log.i( CLASS_NAME, "obj=" + nodes3.getLength() );
Log.i( CLASS_NAME, "hdat=" + nodes4.getLength() );

for (i = 0; i < minimum; i++)
{
    try
    {
        Node copy = dumbNodeCopy( nodes4.item( i ) );
        if ( copy != null )
        {
            // nodes3.item( i ).appendChild( copy );
            nodes3.item( i ).appendChild(
                    nodes3.item( i ).getOwnerDocument().adoptNode( copy ) );
        }
        else
            Log.e( CLASS_NAME, "Copy of nodes4#" + i + ", failed." );
    }
    catch (DOMException dome)
    {
        dome.printStackTrace();
        Log.e( CLASS_NAME, dome.code + "" );
    }
}
```

btw. don't laugh at the code:-) I know that it looks terrible but my imperative ATM is to meet deadlines, and if anyone will propose neat solution I will happily adhere:)